# Encourage people to review

Tags: discussion

How can we encourage people to review first posts, late answers, close votes, etc.? I am asking because my suggested reviews still are not reviewed.

Comment: Probably just an overlook! I mostly look at TSE from my mobile app and unfortunately it does not support reviewing tools!

Comment: the queue is now cleaned-up, there was some backlog indeed!

Comment: @Ezy I think that except suggested edits you should review close votes, first posts, etc.

Comment: i do a lot of those yes

Comment: @Ezy hmmmm, then my too broad flags [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/331) and [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/527). Anyway, review them now and cast a close vote if you think so. Currently, there are 4 close vote posts.

Comment: buddy, i'm not the only one in charges of reviews here. I cleared the queue less than 1 hour ago, voted to close the ones i thought should be closed. I check the queue at least once a day

Comment: @Ezy ok, nvm, good job! When you will be elected you will have a binding vote.

Comment: besides it's my policy not to vote to close recent posts in order to give a chance to the author to improve his post especially if he has low reputation and does not know the rules/expectations. Sorry if i am too lenient compared to other types of enforcement policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you: reviewing is important and we should be encouraging other users to do it. Here are 2 methods I frequently use to get other users to review:

- **Frequently post on meta about reviews you want to discuss.** This could include reviews you think were completed incorrectly, reviews you aren't sure how to complete, etc. Users who come across them on Meta could become interested in your question, and possibly reviewing in general.
- **Set an example and complete some reviews yourself.** Sometimes people end up doing things because other people did. Review and it'll probably encourage others to do so as well. Note: this method requires 350 reputation.