# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Tezos's [first moderator election](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: Ezy] [image: lefessan] [image: Stephen Andrews]

This is [your new moderator team](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5707222195634176/0).

Comment: Thanks Jon! I notice that i am not upgraded to mod status on https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and therefore i am unable to create a private mod chat room for tezos stack exchange as recommended here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271270#271270 . Would it be possible for you to review this ? thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations Ezy, lefessan, and Stephen Andrews, the three new moderators and also [the three top users of the site by reputation](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)! I'm excited for all three of you and I know you'll fulfill your moderation duties will.

While you're still getting familiar with the moderator tools, I would recommend reading these two resources I stumbled upon:

- [Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq)
- [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to the new moderators (Ezy, Stephen Andrews and lefessan) and especially to Ezy who worked hard all this time for both launching this site and asking/answering questions, so now his reputation is increased a lot.

As you are now moderators, spend more time reviewing and cleaning up the site than asking or answering questions. I didn't say that it is not allowed, just spend more time in it :-).

Just an observation (specifically to Ezy for this [robo-review](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/review/close/281); the question should be closed; see my comment): As moderators, you have binding vote, don't be afraid to close a question just some hours after posting because the OP hasn't provided enough details. Just give them some minutes to do it; then close the question. If OP edit their question, then it will be pushed to the reopen queue, so that it can be reopened. Don't take this personally, it was just an improvement attempt from me.

Wish you the best all!

Comment: I agree with most of this, except I don't agree that Ezy's review that you mentioned was not necessarily a robo-review. He's a very attentive reviewer in general, and he could've made a mistake or just misclicked. That doesn't mean he did a robo-review.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle it was a robo-review, but he actually didn't know it. That was a friendly advise. See [Encourage people to review](https://tezos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34) comments.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments! Note on the "robo-review" thing. It was not *robo* in the sense i remember this one and I intentionally left it open. Now this may have been a *mistake* in the sense i was not aware that even if i close the question the author would have a chance to reopen by following the instructions you gave or more precisely since the TSE is new i was afraid of the possibility that someone would be able to step-in to help the user but unable to answer because the OP had not yet adjusted the format of his question. I can see how you disagree with my opinion though!

Comment: @Ezy your welcome! Note that you can still vote to close the question and it will be closed immediately. Additionally, there is one more edit you approved which should have been rejected! It is [this](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/290). It should have been rejected with the message "Clearly conflicts with author's intent". Also, note that hi, thanks, greetings, etc. are considered noise and should be removed. Your other reviews look excellent IMO. Be sure to read the review guidelines before reviewing :) Also, don't be afraid to close questions or reject edits :)

Comment: thanks @double-beep i have now closed the first question you mentioned, I agree this makes sense. Regarding the second i was quite puzzled indeed, i remember that this looked like a big edit, very specific and clearly beyond the OP initial post. I assumed that it must have been either the same person under a different username or perhaps a collaborator of the OP so that's why i did not reject it. If say i DID reject the edit, what is the best way for me to let the edit author be aware of *why* i rejected it (and say ask him to repost the edit under the OP identity) ? thanks!

Comment: @Ezy I am not sure about the privileges you have to check about IP addresses in users, etc. The best way to handle it, is to reject. Just leave a comment under the question saying something like *We have noticed an edit which adds extra info into the post and it is large. The edit has been rejected. If you own the account that suggested that edit, then please don't do this again. Instead, edit your posts with your actual account, so that you can avoid confusions.* This is an example comment, you can modify it or whatever. However, keep in mind that these edits should be rejected.

Comment: thanks @double-beep for the guidance, this makes 100% sense to me so I will use this policy going forward! In this case do you suggest I actually edit, revert this particular edit and add the comment you suggested to me in the comment section ?

Comment: @Ezy now, you can rollback or reject and leave a comment under the question saying to the OP if he created that account. If yes, then say them that isn't allowed because it can lead to serial voting and ***possibly*** nuke the account.

Comment: ok cool i will proceed now.

Comment: @Ezy good luck! Some extra advices: be sure to check every day at least two times the mod-flag queue and create a private chat with other moderators in https://chat.stackexchange.com, so that you can discuss site issues or whenever you had a disagreement. Good luck again!

Comment: @double-beep : in the chat i can only create public rooms or gallery rooms but not strictly user-restricted rooms. Is there a standard way to create rooms for mods only ?

Comment: @Ezy see [A guide to moderating chat](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/271270) and especially `Mod tools – private room access`. Go [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) and then select private. If it doesn't exist, then create a gallery and then go to settings in `info>access` and select `private`. If it doesn't exist, let me know.

Comment: @double-beep i went to the link you mentioned and there is no "private" option like i said the first time. I proceeded to create the room as a gallery and clicked on "access" and there is still no "private" option. Please advise!

Comment: @Ezy try this instead: create the chat room at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new. Make sure the related site is Tezos. Go to "info" link of the chat room at the right side of the page, and click on the "access" tab. You should then be at a screen that looks kinda like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baTLI.png), except with a "private" or "read-only" option as well (and the design might look slightly different too, I took the screenshot on MSE chat). Just click that, hit "save changes", and then the chat room should be read-only.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard thanks however this was not working neither. In the end the glitch happened beacause i did not have my chat account linked with my tse account so when i acquired mod privilege on tse i did not get the same privilege on chat